# how to check if the element have moving to the left?

Tags: jquery

I have got a problem with checking on the element, I am trying to find out how to check on the element 'rowSubPgm' if they have been moving to the left using with rowwidth3.

I have tried this:

```
  if(current_row == 4 && currentdivwidth[0] == 517)
  {
    if($('.rowSubPgm').css( "margin-left", "-"+(rowwidth3)+"px"))
    {
      alert("now let do something");
    }

    $('.span2hrfor1hr30mins').each(function(i,e)
    {
      if($(e).hasClass('row2') && $(e).hasClass('span2hrfor1hr30mins'))
      {
        $('.rowSubPgm').css( "margin-left", "-"+(rowwidth3)+"px" );
        $(e).attr('row2'); $(e).removeClass('span2hrfor1hr30mins').addClass('span2hrfor1hr');
      }
    });
```

I can get pass on the 'if current_row == 4 && currentdivwidth[0] == 517' statement when i am on the column four with the size 517, but I can't be able to check on the element 'rowSubPgm' if they have been moving to the left using with rowwidth3.

Do you know how i can check on the element if they have been moving to the left using with rowwidth3?

Comment: Can you please provide a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/AaG2W/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about checking the CSS margin-left property?  This is a 'technical-level' solution.

```
var marginValue = $('.rowSubPgm').css( 'margin-left');   // gets CSS from first.
console.log('margin value=', marginValue);
if (marginValue) {  // is non-empty
    console.log('margin value detected!', marginValue);
    // now do something, based on that.
}
```

It would, however, probably be better to do a 'design-level' solution -- toggling a CSS class, or using jQuery data, to mark your application's logical state.

```
if ($('.rowSubPgm').hasClass( 'Row_IsShifted')) {
    // this class is specific to your applications, 
    //    and decouples logic from your specific implementation.
}
```

Maybe the 'span2hrfor1hr' class is a suitable logical marker, maybe not? (I don't understand the overview of what your application is intended to be doing.)

```
if ($('.rowSubPgm').hasClass( 'span2hrfor1hr')) {
```

If you do use a CSS class, this may also be able to drive the margin-left setting (if that is not dynamic) and perhaps some other formatting.

Comment: I have tried both of them and they doesn't work. i want to check on $('.rowSubPgm').css( "margin-left", "-"+(rowwidth3)+"px" ); if it have been return true then do something. i have tried 'if $('.rowSubPgm').css( "margin-left", "-"+(rowwidth3)+"px" )' it doesn't work. any idea?

Comment: Try `if ($('.rowSubPgm').css( "margin-left") == ("-"+rowwidth3+"px"))` as a condition, but best to grab the CSS margin-left property out into a variable & log it's value so you can debug this!

Comment: Your code needs enough debugging, Chris, that you can see what's going on. Get your key information into variables, and print them, if your code doesn't work!

Comment: H: Thank you very much for your help, i can see that the problem is now solved! Thank you so much for your help.